# Stack of Objects "cannot find symbol" when calling method

Tags: java, inheritance, stack

So I have a class which is extended called "Furniture." I'm making stacks of each type of furniture I make and storing the stacks inside of an array.

```
   class Furniture{
    private String color;
    private String style;
    private String height;
    private String width;   
    private String depth;

    public Furniture(String c)
    {
    color = c;
    }
    public Furniture(String s, String c)
    {
    color = c;
    style = s;
    }
    public Furniture(String h, String w, String d, String c)
    {
    height = h;
    width = w;
    depth = d;
    color = c;
    }
    public Furniture(String s, String h, String c)
    {
    style = s;
    height = h;
    color = c;
    }
    public String getColor()
    {
    return color;
    }
}
```

The class is extended

```
class Bed extends Furniture
{
    private String size;
    public Bed(String sz,String c){
    super(c);
    size = sz;
    }
}
```

I then try to call my getColor() method

```
Stack s = new Stack();
s.push(new Bed("queen","red"));
System.out.println(s.peek().getColor());
```

`java:195: error: cannot find symbol`
`System.out.println(s.peek().getColor());`

```
symbol:   method getColor()
location: class Object
```

I'm not sure how to address this

Answer (score 2):

The error is because, when you **peek()** stack top element, it returns **Object** class object which does not contain **getColor()** method. So you just need to create the **Stack** with generic parameter **Bed**

You have to change

```
Stack s = new Stack();
```

to

```
Stack<Bed> s = new Stack<Bed>();
```

Now when you peek stack top element, it will return **Bed** object not **Object** object. So **getColor()** can be resolved.

Comment: This works! How would I implement it if I want to make a regular array of five stacks each holding different types?

Comment: You mean, Stack<A>, Stack<B> etc in an array?

Comment: Yes, as in Stack<Bed> in array[0] and Stack<Desk> in array[1]

Comment: You can simple add all those creating an array of Stack, like Stack[] a = {the references separated by comma}; But you need to be very cautious of ClassCastException here.

Comment: As in something like `Stack[] s = {new Stack<Bed>(), new Stack<Table>()}` ?

Comment: Hm, when I do this I get the same errors as earlier.

`Stack[] s = {new Stack<Bed>(), new Stack<Table>()}`
`s[0].push(new Bed("Queen","red"));`
`System.out.println(s[0].peek.getColor());`

Comment: Its because of the same reason what I have said in my answer, you have to cast here, I mean s[0].peek() cast this to Bed and than invoke getColor() like ((Bed)s[0].peek()).getColor()

Answer (score 1):

Your stack has no template so it will default to holding Objects. Therefore, the object that is returned with `peek()` is seen as class Object and not like class Bed. And as you can see, Java cannot find a `getColor()` method in Object because there isn't one.

Here's how you fix it:

```
Stack<Bed> s = new Stack<Bed>();
```

Answer (score -1):

You should make an object of the class Furniture as -

`Furniture f=new Furniture("queen","red");`

This will do the following :

1.Create an object of the class Furniture with name f

2.Assign size of f as queen and its color as red.

And now if you want to print the color of this object,you should call it this way :

`System.out.println(f.getColor());`

Comment: Objects don't have names, and the rest of your answer is very unclear - he's clearly trying to get the color of "whatever is on the stack", not just for one object which can be referred to by a single variable.

Comment: Name as in that object f. Anyways,I use this method for a single object and if I need multiple entries,I just use Array Of Objects. Sorry if the answer doesn't suit you. My bad. :( . I didn't know about the Stack<Bed> so I tried `Stack<Bed> obj = new Stack<Bed>();`. Works! Learnt something new. Thanks!

Comment: `f` isn't an object, it's a variable. You should *definitely* distinguish between the two; they're very different concepts.

Answer (score -2):

Stack is in java.util. You did peek() is in built method of Stack class. So, you can not call like s.peek().getColor(). If you have defined getColor() method in any of your class, you need to create object of that class then you can use method of that class.   You are getting `Cannot find symbol` because there no method like getColor() in java's Stack class.

Comment: He's not trying to call `getColor()` on `Stack`. The problem is due to not using generics properly - see Chandra Sekhar's answer.